# Convert values between two normal distributions

Tags: r, normal-distribution, mean, standard-deviation, quantiles

Imagine, for example, I have two normal distributions of scaled scores:

```
Normal distribution #1: mean 200, standard deviation 10
Normal distribution #2: mean 150, standard deviation 15
```

**How can I "convert" a value between the two distributions?**

At the moment I am looking for a better approach because I am calculating the percentile of the value of the distribution #1 and then I am calculating the value corresponding to the same percentile of the distribution #2.

(I use R)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You convert the original to a centered score by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. Then multiply by the new standard deviation and add the mean. With $x$ from the former distribution (with mean 200) and $y$ from the latter, the formula is

$y = \frac{x - 200}{10} * 15 + 150$

This is the same as calculating the corresponding percentiles 
cumulative distribution values.

Comment: Yes, you can actually even simplify the formula to $1.5 \cdot x - 150$, although the form above is more intuitive.